# How do I restart loop when "NoSuchElementException" error occurs?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get my code to restart my loop when NoSuchElementException occurs. It's a basic check for price loop until price is met, but sometimes the code cannot find the element upon refresh. How can I restart it automatically and loop until price condition is met? Here is the code.

```
buy_price = int(8000)
price_found = False

while not price_found:
    try:
        price_id = "price_on_page"
        current_price = wd.find_element_by_id(price_id).text
        store_price = int(current_price)
        
        if store_price <= buy_price:
            price_found = True
            add_to_cart_button = wd.find_element_by_xpath('add_cart_element')
            add_to_cart_button.click()
        else
            time.sleep(random_wait_time)
            wd.refresh()
    except NoSuchElementException:
            print("NoSuchElementException occurred. Restarting the code...")
            time.sleep(300)
            wd.refresh()

purchase_button = wd.find_element_by_xpath('purchase_code')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WebDriverWait` to wait for the element to be present.

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
add_to_cart_button = WebDriverWait(wd, 10).until(
     EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "add_cart_element")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
buy_price = int(8000)
while True:
    try:
        price_id = "price_on_page"
        current_price = wd.find_element_by_id(price_id).text
        store_price = int(current_price)
        if store_price <= buy_price:
            add_to_cart_button = wd.find_element_by_xpath('add_cart_element')
            add_to_cart_button.click()
            break
        else:
            time.sleep(random_wait_time)
            wd.refresh()
            continue
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("NoSuchElementException occurred. Restarting the code...")
        time.sleep(300)
        wd.refresh()
        continue
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you! Also, how can I add different Exceptions errors to the code in order to restart on others as well?